# Simplest way to write output message to 'output window' in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I've tried `OutputDebugString` function and most of the time I get error like :

> error C2664: 'OutputDebugStringA' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'LPCSTR'

Examples

**Attempt 1:**

```
//ERROR: sprintf is unsafe. Use sprintf_s instead
int x = 4;
char s[256];
sprintf(s, "There is %d numbers", x);
OutputDebugString((LPCWSTR)s);
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
//FAIL: outputs junk (sprintf_s doesn't understand unicode?)
int x = 4;
char s[256];
sprintf_s(s, "There is %d numbers", x);
OutputDebugString((LPCWSTR)s);
```

**Attempt 3:**

```
//ERROR: no instance of overloaded function "sprintf_s" matches the argument list
int x = 4;
TCHAR s[256];
sprintf_s(s, "There is %d numbers", x);
OutputDebugString((LPCWSTR)s);
```

**Attempt 4:**

```
//ERROR: no instance of overloaded function "sprintf_s" matches the argument list
int x = 4;
TCHAR s[256];
sprintf_s(s, L"There is %d numbers", x);
OutputDebugString((LPCWSTR)s);
```

**Attempt 5:**

```
//ERROR: no instance of overloaded function "swprintf" matches the argument list
int x = 4;
TCHAR s[256];
swprintf(s, "There is %d numbers", x);
OutputDebugString(s);
```

**Attempt 6:**

```
//ERROR: 'swprintf': function has been changed to confirm with the ISO C standard, adding an extra character count parameter
int x = 4;
TCHAR s[256];
swprintf(s, L"There is %d numbers", x);
OutputDebugString(s);
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It only accepts a string as a parameter, not an integer. Try something like

```
sprintf(msgbuf, "My variable is %d\n", integerVariable);
OutputDebugString(msgbuf);
```

For more info take a look at http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/outputdebugstring.html

Comment: + @Jon: Even better yet, consider using std::stringstream.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: I used std::stringstream instead of sprintf/sprintf_s as you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: @BillyONeal Can you explain why using stringstream would be better? Just curious.

Comment: @TrevorHart Bill of 2017 doesn't wholly agree with Bill of 2010. The primary advantage is not needing to worry about the destination buffer size. But there are plenty of uses for sprintf:)

Comment: @BillyONeal How would you use `std::stringstream`? What is the syntax?

Comment: What do you declare `msgbuf` as? `sprintf`  takes a `char *` and `OutputDebugString` takes a `LPCWSTR`. So i can't figure out a declaration of `msgbuf` that would compile.

Answer (score 15):

For debugging purposes you could use [`_RPT` macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa298568%28VS.60%29.aspx).

For instance,

```
_RPT1( 0, "%d\n", my_int_value );
```

Answer (score 11):

The most common way I'm aware of is the `TRACE` macro:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wyz8787%28VS.80%29.aspx

For example:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 16;
float z = 32.0;
TRACE( "This is a TRACE statement\n" );

TRACE( "The value of x is %d\n", x );

TRACE( "x = %d and y = %d\n", x, y );

TRACE( "x = %d and y = %x and z = %f\n", x, y, z );
```

Comment: It seems TRACE is defined in MFC, which I'm not using.

Answer (score 7):

I found this answer when searching the error message:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/29800589

Basically, you just need put an "L" in front of your output string when using `OutputDebugString`:

```
OutputDebugString(L"test\n");
```

It worked great for me.

Edit:

For formatting strings with data, I ended up using

```
char buffer[100];
sprintf_s(buffer, "check it out: %s\n", "I can inject things");
OutputDebugStringA(buffer);
```

By no means am I an expert, I just found something that worked and moved on.

Comment: That doesn't account for if I want to format the string and pass data to it.

Comment: I added my solution that worked for injection.  I specialize in the iOS platform and languages, please don't regard this as an expert solution  :)

Comment: Depending on your compiler options and settings `OutputDebugString` is translated into one of two targets, `OutputDebugStringW` for wide text characters (`wchart_t`) or `OutputDebugStringA` for narrow text characters (`char`). The `L` is required for creating a `wchar_t` wide character string as in `L"wide char"` versus `"narrow char"`. The `sprintf_s()` function uses narrow characters, standard `char` type, so the `char buffer[100];` content is printed to the Output window using `OutputDebugStringA()` to force the use of narrow character text.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
OutputDebugStringA("Some random text");
```

Or:

```
OutputDebugString("Some random text");
```

Comment: 2nd will not work if _UNICODE is defined

Answer (score 0):

To use OutputDebugString(), provide `char *` or `const char *` as parameter:

```
OutputDebugString("This is an output");
```