# Calling OutputDebugString in a C++ UWP project

Tags: c++, uwp

I'm trying to add a simple diagnostic output to a C++ UWP shared project akin to `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` in C#. Following the documentation for OutputDebugString here and this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3179234/575530) I've tried this:

```cplusplus
char buf[1024];
sprintf(buf, "frequency = %f", (float)result);
OutputDebugString(buf);
```

but I get the compiler error

> argument of type "char*" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"

How do I fix this?

Comment: Use OutputDebugStringA() if you want to display a char[].

Comment: That worked - thanks Hans (N.B. I also needed to swap `sprintf` to `sprintf_s`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A colleague advised me to add

```
#include "strsafe.h"
```

after any pre-compiled headers and then use this code instead

```
TCHAR buf[1024];
size_t cbDest = 1024 * sizeof(TCHAR);
StringCbPrintf(buf, cbDest, TEXT("frequency = %f"), (float)result);
OutputDebugString(buf);
```

I also needed to remember to swap the debugger to handle mixed code:

[image: VS2015 screenshot]

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381407(v=vs.85).aspx describes when TCHAR is char or wchar_t, etc

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I use most of the time (notice the "L"):

```
#include <Windows.h>
OutputDebugString(L"Sarah Connor ?\n");
```