# C++ std::out dont print in debug window

Tags: c++, visual-studio-debugging, cout

this is a quick question.
I am building a program in C++ and have this weird problem when it comes to print some data in the output window. I don't get any data in the output window but when I set a breakpoint I can see that data is in the variable that I am trying to print. So I am going a bit loco here.

This is the line I use to print my data:

```
std::cout << midiNoteNumber << std::endl;
```

Why does nothing appear in the debugging output window?

Comment: This one line on its own is not enough information for us to help. Please include a [MCVE], and include details on how you compile and run it. (My initial suspicion is regarding the **type** of `midiNoteNumber` - what is it?)

Comment: show the whole function ? can't get the context.

Comment: The debug console in visual studio doesn't pipe from stdout. Never has. Use OutputDebugString if you want debug console output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print to the debug output window in a Win32 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333527/how-do-i-print-to-the-debug-output-window-in-a-win32-app)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect stdout to output window from visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248704/how-to-redirect-stdout-to-output-window-from-visual-studio)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179199/simplest-way-to-write-output-message-to-output-window-in-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score -2):

OutputDebugString is nothing that I could get working so I solved it by doing this:

```
_RPT1(0, "%d\n", midiNoteNumber);
```

Comment: What is ```_RPT1```? Where is it from?

Comment: Please improve this answer. At the moment it is not helpful, as it is missing information to be useful to others.

Comment: OutputDebugString is a macro which calls the appropriate function depending if You are using Wide characters(Unicode) or not. If You are using wide chars, then before the string literal You should add a L example: ```L"Debug output"```